Using 'const' or 'let' statements in a switch-case block in vue3
I'm making a game and trying to be clever, I tried to consolidate working code into a case statement so I didnt have to deal with duplicate statements.
I'm getting a "Unexpected lexical declaration in case block"
Which come from statements like
    switch(card.id) {
              case '016': // Crucible King Dios IV
                
                
                // Get all valid targets for magic attack
 ===>>>          const targets = this.getMagicTargets(sourceIndex, 

Should I just declare them all prior to the switch statements using lets then assign them in the switch statement, or is there another way of handling this? full code below for reference.
switch(card.id) {
          case '016': //         
            
            // Get all valid targets for magic attack
       const targets = this.getMagicTargets(sourceIndex, card.secondaryAttackPattern);
            console.log('Magic attack targets:', targets);
            
            // Process each target
            for (const targetIndex of targets) {
              const targetCard = this.cells[targetIndex].card;
              if (!targetCard) continue;
              
              // Apply magic damage directly
              console.log(`Dealing ${damage} magic damage to ${targetCard.name}`);
              targetCard.hp -= damage;
              
              if (targetCard.hp <= 0) {
                console.log(`${targetCard.name} was destroyed by magic`);
                this.handleCardDestruction(targetIndex);
              }
            }
            break;
            
          case '030': // 
          case '048': // 
          case '70' : // 
            // Handle regular attacks...
            const validTargets = this.getValidTargets(sourceIndex);

            if (validTargets.length === 0) {
              console.log('No valid targets found');
              console.groupEnd();
              return;
            }

            const hasMultiPattern = card.secondaryAttackPattern.some(pattern => 
              pattern.includes('multi')
            );

            // Track all attacks for counter-attack phase
            const attackSequence = [];


TNo that actually helps, thanks. You can close this.
